# Python Regular Expression Named Capture Groups

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, capture-group, named-captures

Im learning regular expressions, specifically named capture groups.

Having an issue where I'm not able to figure out how to write an if/else statement for my function **findVul()**.

Basically how the code works or should work is that **findVul()** goes through **data1** and **data2**, which has been added to the list **myDATA**.

If the regex finds a match for the entire named group, then it should print out the results. It currently works perfectly.

**CODE:**

```
import re

data1 = '''

dwadawa231d .2 vulnerabilities discovered dasdfadfad .One vulnerability discovered 123e2121d21 .12 vulnerabilities discovered sgwegew342 dawdwadasf

2r3232r32ee

'''

data2 = ''' d21d21 .2 vul discovered adqdwdawd .One vulnerability disc d12d21d .two vulnerabilities discovered 2e1e21d1d f21f21

'''

def findVul(data):
    pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<VUL>(\d{1,2}|One)\s+(vulnerabilities|vulnerability)\s+discovered)')
    match = re.finditer(pattern, data)

    for x in match:
        print(x.group())


myDATA = [data1,data2] count_data = 1

for x in myDATA:
    print('\n--->Reading data{0}\n'.format(count_data))
    count_data+=1
    findVul(x)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
--->Reading data1

2 vulnerabilities discovered
One vulnerability discovered
12 vulnerabilities discovered

--->Reading data2
```

Now I want to add an if/else statement to check if there are any matches for the entire named group.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**CODE:**

```
def findVul(data):
    pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<VUL>(\d{1,2}|One)\s+(vulnerabilities|vulnerability)\s+discovered)')
    match = re.finditer(pattern, data)

    if len(list(match)) != 0:
        print('\nVulnerabilities Found!\n')
        for x in match:
            print(x.group())

    else:
        print('No Vulnerabilities Found!\n')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
--->Reading data1


Vulnerabilities Found!


--->Reading data2

No Vulnerabilities Found!
```

As you can see it does not print the vulnerabilities that should be in **data1**.

Could someone please explain the correct way to do this and why my logic is wrong. 
Thanks so much :) !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some more research after @AdamKG response.

I wanted to utlize the re.findall() function.

re.findall() will return a list of all matched substrings. In my case I have capture groups inside of my named capture group. This will return a list with tuples.

For example the following regex with data1:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<VUL>(\d{1,2}|One)\s+ 
(vulnerabilities|vulnerability)\s+discovered)')

match = re.findall(pattern, data)
```

Will return a list with tuples:

```
[('2 vulnerabilities discovered', '2', 'vulnerabilities'), ('One vulnerability 
discovered', 'One', 'vulnerability'), ('12 vulnerabilities discovered', '12', 
'vulnerabilities')]
```

**My Final Code for findVul():**

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<VUL>(\d{1,2}|One)\s+(vulnerabilities|vulnerability)\s+discovered)')
match = re.findall(pattern, data)

if len(match) != 0:
    print('Vulnerabilties Found!\n')
    for x in match:
        print('--> {0}'.format(x[0]))
else:
    print('No Vulnerability Found!\n')
```

Comment: Just a side note: you can shorten your Regex a bit with `(vulnerabilit(?:y|ies))` part :) But on the other side it becomes a bit less legible. [Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EHurjy/2)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) returns an iterator that is evaluated when you do the `len(list(match)) != 0` test; when you iterate over it again in the for-loop, it is already exhausted and there are no items left. The simple fix is just to add a `match = list(match)` line after the `finditer()` call.

Comment: thanks so much AdamKG ! , this is my first time using the re.finditer() function , i usually use re.findall() . Would implementing re.finditer() be the best way to find my named capture group or is there a better way ?